# Terminal not working with color-prompt

Tags: bash, history

If I do this:

```
echo foo
PS1='\e[0;30mtest \e[0m'
```

and then presses the <kbd>up arrow</kbd> `test PS1='\e[0;30mtest \e[0m'` appears (as expected).
But if I press <kbd>up arrow</kbd>, so I should have `echo foo`, it results in `test PS1='\e[0;3echo foo`

If I set the PS1 to anything which doesn't include color it works:

```
echo foo
PS1='\e[0;30mtest \e[0m'
PS1='test '
```

- triple press <kbd>up arrow</kbd>, results in `echo foo`

Note: `echo foo` is still the command executed if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I have tried this in both iTerm2 and the apple Terminal.

Why is it doing that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
PS1="\[\e[0;30m\]test \[\e[0m\]"
```

By using extra `\[` and `\]` brackets, you are telling `bash` that you've got some non-printing characters, which it may be misinterpreting when you press the up-arrow.

Answer (score 1):

```
PS1='\[\e[0;30m\]test \[\e[0m\]'
#    ^^        ^^     ^^     ^^
```

The `\[` and `\]` tell bash about non-printing characters; otherwise it has no idea
how long your prompt actually is, hence the mangled prompt.  See the `PROMPTING` section
of the bash manpage for more details.