# New lines no longer work in terminal with custom prompt

Tags: bash, redhat

I set my prompt to have colors: `PS1='\e[3;32m[\u@\h:\W]$ \e[m'`

However, now very long commands no longer automatically cause a new line to appear. Instead, commands that go longer than one line will start appearing at the left side of the current line, overwriting the current characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Terminal not working with color-prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950769/terminal-not-working-with-color-prompt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Non-printing characters in the prompt need to be enclosed in `\[...\]` so that `bash` can accurately compute the visible length of the prompt.

```
PS1='\[\e[3;32m\][\u@\h:\W]$ \[\e[m\]'
     ^^        ^^            ^^    ^^
```

`bash` itself doesn't know that those bytes will not be displayed by the terminal; it is your terminal that, instead of displaying the 7-byte sequence `\e[3;32m`, simply changes the color used to display the following characters. `\u`, on the other hand, is replaced by the users name by `bash` itself, so you don't have to do anything special to tell `bash` how to properly handle it.

Comment: For the next person: you have to do this even if you use `$(tput setaf 1)` to set your colors. I didn't think you had to but I was wrong. It'll end up looking like `"\[$(tput setaf 1)\]"`.

Comment: A PS1 that uses a function to create the prompt has to handle this differently, see: http://superuser.com/questions/301353/escape-non-printing-characters-in-a-function-for-a-bash-prompt